# If $X$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu$, prove $\int \limits_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} x \, \mu(dx)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm trying to prove $\int \limits_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} x \,\mu(dx)$ if $X$ is a random variable defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

I understand how to prove this for indicator functions.  I'm not sure how to prove it for simple functions.  Specifically, let $s(\omega) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \chi_{A_{i}}(\omega)$, where $\alpha_{i} \neq 0$ and $P(A_{i}) < \infty$ for each $i$ and the $A_{i}$'s are pairwise disjoint.  Then we have:

$\int \limits_{\Omega} s(\omega) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Omega} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \chi_{A_{i}}(\omega) \,dP(\omega) =  \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}  \alpha_{i} \int \limits_{\Omega} \chi_{A_{i}}(\omega) \,dP(\omega) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}  \alpha_{i} \int \limits_{\Bbb R} x \, \mu_{i}(dx)$ (where $\mu_{i}$ is the distribution measure of $\chi_{A_{i}}(\omega)$).

Now what?  How can I say that this integral equals $\int \limits_{\Bbb R} x \,\mu(dx)$, where $\mu$ is the distribution of $s(\omega)$?  Is the distribution of $s(\omega)$ equal to the "sum" of distributions of its indicator functions?

Also, how would you then prove this for a non-negative measurable function?  I know you would use a sequence of simple functions increasing up to the function, but I'm not sure how to move the limit from out of the integral back into it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think is a more clear proof for a beginner (though aside from notation, the ideas are pretty much the same as one of the other answers):

**Claim:**  Suppose $X$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu$.  Then $\int \limits_{\Omega} X(\omega) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} x \,\mu(dx)$.

To prove this claim, we will prove a stronger statement, which is the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu$.  Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be any measurable function such that either $f \geq 0$ or $E[|f(X(\omega))|] < \infty$.  Then $\int \limits_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f(x) \,\mu(dx)$.

*Proof.*  We will first prove this for $f$ a characteristic function, then $f$ a simple function, followed by $f$ a non-negative measurable function, and finally $f$ an integrable function.

For characteristic functions:

> Let $B \in \Bbb B(\Bbb R)$ and suppose $f = \Bbb 1_{B}$.  Then $\int \limits_{\Omega} \Bbb 1_{B}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) =\int \limits_{X^{-1}(B)} 1 \,dP(\omega) + \int \limits_{\Omega - X^{-1}(B)} 0 \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{X^{-1}(B)}  1 \,dP(\omega) = P(X^{-1}(B)) = \mu(B) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} \Bbb 1_{B}(x) \,\mu(dx)$.

Now for simple functions:

> Let $s(x) = \sum \limits_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \chi_{A_{i}}(x)$.  Then $\int \limits_{\Omega} s(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) =\int \limits_{\Omega} \sum \limits_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \chi_{A_{i}}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) =  \sum \limits_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \int \limits_{\Omega}\chi_{A_{i}}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) $
>
> $= \sum \limits_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \int \limits_{\Bbb R}\chi_{A_{i}}(x) \,\mu(dx) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} \sum \limits_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \chi_{A_{i}}(x) \,\mu(dx) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} s(x) \,\mu(dx)$.

Now if $f \geq 0$ is measurable, then find a monotonically increasing sequence of simple functions $s_{n}$ such that $s_{n} \to f$, and we have:

> $\int \limits_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Omega} \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) \underbrace{=}_{\text{by MCT}}  \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int \limits_{\Omega} s_{n}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega)$
>
> $ = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int \limits_{\Bbb R} s_{n}(x) \,\mu(dx) \underbrace{=}_{\text{by MCT}}  \int \limits_{\Bbb R} \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n}(x) \,\mu(dx) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R}  f(x) \,\mu(dx)$

Up to now, we haven't needed the assumption that $E[|f(X(\omega))|] < \infty$, but we will use to now.

Final case: $f$ satisfies the integrability condition in the previous sentence:

> Decompose $f$ into $f^{+} - f^{-}$.  Then $E[|f(X(\omega))|] < \infty$ implies  $E[f^{+}(X(\omega))] < \infty$ and $E[f^{-}(X(\omega))] < \infty$, so:
>
> $\int \limits_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Omega} f^{+}(X(\omega)) - f^{-}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) $
>
> $= \int \limits_{\Omega} f^{+}(X(\omega))\,dP(\omega) - \int \limits_{\Omega} f^{-}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f^{+}(x)\,\mu(dx) - \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f^{-}(x) \,\mu(dx)$
>
> $ = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f^{+}(x) - f^{-}(x) \,\mu(dx) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f(x) \,\mu(dx)$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\mu$ is that $\mu(B)=P(X^{-1}(B))$, for $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ and measurable. You've got a sum of indicators, and you've proven the result for single indicators. So when looking at $\int_\mathbb{R}xd\mu(x)$, just split $\mathbb{R}$ into sets $B_1,B_2,\cdots$, where $B_i=X(A_i)$. You can always rewrite any simple function into one that's a sum over disjoint sets, so this will imply $B_i$ are disjoint too, allowing you to decompose the integral into a sum.

Comment: So what about my last question with a nonnegative measurable function?

Comment: I meant my last question that I asked in the problem description.

Comment: @user46944: you can switch limits as long as your sequence is uniform. You can always approximate bounded measurable functions uniformly, right? Then after you can approximate bounded ones, move onto unbounded ones by cutting off at an appropriate height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you run into with the $X\ge0$ part of your proof is when you convert to $EX_n$ to $\int x\mu_n(dx)$, you can't use MCT on the right side (here, $\mu_n$ is the measure induced by $X_n$, for simple $X_n$ approaching $X$).  I think it is easier to prove the more general fact that
$$
Ef(X)=\int f(x)\,\mu(dx)
$$
for any measurable $f$. The proof method is the same, except you start with simple $f$, then $f\ge 0$, then all $f$, instead of doing the same for $X$. To get your result, set $f(x)=x$.

**Addendum:** Suppose $f$ is an indicator function, $f(x)=1_{x\in A}$. Then

$$Ef(X)=E1_{X\in A}=P(X\in A)=\mu(A)=\int 1_{x\in A}\,\mu(dx)$$

The third equality is the definition of $\mu$. When $f=\sum c_i1_{A_i}$ is simple, then
\begin{align*}
Ef(X)=E\sum c_i1_{X\in A_i}=\sum c_iE1_{X\in A_i}=\sum c_i\int 1_{x\in A_i}\,\mu(dx)
&=\int \sum c_i1_{x\in A_i} \,d\mu(dx)\\
&=\int f(x)\,\mu(dx)
\end{align*}

Now, suppose $f\ge 0$. Let $f_n$ be a sequence of simple functions so that $f_n\to f$ pointwise, and $f_n\ge f_{n-1}$. For example, you could pick $f_n=\min(\lfloor 2^nf \rfloor/2^n,n)$. Then by the Monotone convergence theorem,
$$
Ef(X)=E\lim_n f_n(X)=\lim_n E f_n(X)=\lim_n \int f_n(x)\,\mu(dx)= \int \lim_n f_n(x)\,\mu(dx)= \int f(x)\,\mu(dx)
$$

Comment: You are absolutely right in your assessment of the problem that I run into.  But I don't understand your fix.  What is your $\mu$ when you are proving the statement in the last line?  Shouldn't $\mu$ change with $f_{n}$?

Comment: No, $\mu$ is the measure induced by $X$. Namely, $\mu(A)=P(X\in A)$. Since $\mu$ only depends on $X$, it doesn't change as $f_n$ changes. If you have access to Probability, by Durrett, this is Theorem 1.6.9.

Comment: Ok, so how do I know $E[f_{n}(X)] = \int f_{n}(x) \,\mu(dx)$?  This step requires knowing that $\int \limits_{\Omega} f_{n}(X) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f_{n}(x) \,\mu(dx)$, which I can't justify.  I know you thought I would be able to prove the earlier cases of indicator function and simple function on my own, but I guess I actually need to see those arguments.  Do you have time to type them up?

Comment: @user46944 see my addendum

Comment: It's important to specify that $f$ is a function taking $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, right?  Why is $E[\mathbb{1}_{X \in A}] = P(X^{-1}(A))$?

Comment: Actually, I want to revise my question.  What is $E[1_{ \{\omega : X(\omega) \in A \} }]$?  In other words, what is $E[\mathbb{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}]$?

Comment: Yes, you need $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is measurable. $1_{X^{-1}(A)}$ is an indicator function, so its expectation is by definition the probability of the event it indicates, so $E1_{X^{-1}(A)}=P(X^{-1}(A))$.

Comment: I'm so confused.  If $f$ is supposed to be a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, then why is $\mathbb{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}$ a function from $\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I can't upvote your answer or choose it as best unless I understand it.  If you don't want to contribute to this question anymore, it's okay, but from my understanding there are details of your answer that are unexplained.